# Grails: Error including platform-ui plugin in war file

Tags: grails, war, grails-plugin

I have created a new Grails 2.2 app that contains the platform-ui-1.0.RC5 plugin. Whenever I use the Grails “run-app” command to start the app in development mode, everything works OK. However, if I run “prod run-war” or war up the app and run it under Tomcat on a separate server, I get the following error:

> Oct 31, 2013 8:07:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext Oct 31, 2013
>   8:07:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'instanceTagLibraryApi': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.setGspTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.platform.ThemeTagLib':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsThemes': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'grailsViewFinder' while setting bean property
>   'grailsViewFinder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsViewFinder': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'precompiledGspMap'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.setGspTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.platform.ThemeTagLib':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsThemes': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'grailsViewFinder' while setting bean property
>   'grailsViewFinder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsViewFinder': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'precompiledGspMap'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.platform.ThemeTagLib':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsThemes': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'grailsViewFinder' while setting bean property
>   'grailsViewFinder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsViewFinder': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'precompiledGspMap'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.grails.plugin.platform.ThemeTagLib':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsThemes': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'grailsViewFinder' while setting bean property
>   'grailsViewFinder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsViewFinder': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'precompiledGspMap'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsThemes': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'grailsViewFinder' while setting bean property
>   'grailsViewFinder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsViewFinder': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'precompiledGspMap'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsViewFinder': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'precompiledGspMap'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean
>   class specified on bean definition    ... 5 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean
>   definition    ... 5 more
>
> Oct 31, 2013 8:07:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart Oct 31, 2013 8:07:28 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/zdummy] startup failed due to previous errors

Here is the “plugins” section of my BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile ":platform-ui:1.0.RC5"
   }
```

I commented out the platform-ui plugin.
Refreshed the dependencies.
Ran the Grails clean command.
Ran the project using “prod run-war” and it ran correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: try to use grails war

Comment: Thank you.  I'm getting the error with both grails run-war and grails war.  The problem did not occur with earlier versions of the plugin, such as 1.0.RC3.

Comment: raise an issue, https://github.com/MerryCoders/grails-platform-ui/issues :)

Comment: Opened an issue - thanks.